# MSDeploy - sync command to copy files to subfolder of iis app

Tags: iis, jenkins, msbuild, iis-6, msdeploy

I want to perform a post-build step to copy some files into a website folder using MSDeploy.

Eventually I'll be doing this to a remote location (specifying `computerName`, `userName` switches etc.), but for now I'm running it locally:

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" 
   -AllowUntrusted -verb:sync 
   -source:dirPath="D:\files_to_copy" 
   -dest:iisApp="My Website Name"
```

This works, but it removes **all** contents of the website folder and replaces them with the contents of "D:\files_to_copy" (as you might expect!). So I was wondering how I use this simply copy to a subfolder within the site?

I've tried `-dest:iisApp="My Website Name/my_subfolder"` but this just creates a new IIS app called "my_subfolder" nested within the existing IIS app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are [providers](http://technet.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/dd569040%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) other than iisApp, maybe dirPath is the one you want for `-dest` aswell?:

- [dirPath](http://technet.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/ee207412%28v=ws.10%29.aspx): The dirPath provider synchronizes directory content.
- [filePath](http://technet.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/ee207414%28v=ws.10%29.aspx): The filePath provider synchronizes individual files.
- [iisApp](http://technet.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/dd569054%28v=ws.10%29.aspx): The iisApp provider synchronizes directory content to a folder and marks the folder as an application.
- [contentPath](http://technet.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/dd569034%28v=ws.10%29.aspx): The contentPath provider synchronizes Web site content.

Comment: The main issue with dirPath is that I don't want to specify an absolute path.  Instead I just want to add it to the website, regardless of where it's actually located (sorry I should've mentioned this in my question).  Is there any way of dynamically getting the path of the IIS app using environment variables or something similar?

Comment: I haven't used it, but could "contentPath" be what you are looking for? Afraid I do not have the infrastructure to do a test for you.

Answer (score 4):

Anders's answer above provides the correct information, but the full code I used to successfully carry this out is as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" 
  -AllowUntrusted -verb:sync 
  -source:contentPath="D:\files_to_copy" 
  -dest:contentPath="My Website Name\my_new_folder"
```

Adding a single file to the root of the site (for example **robots.txt**) can be done using the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" 
  -AllowUntrusted -verb:sync 
  -source:contentPath="D:\my_folder\robots.txt" 
  -dest:contentPath="My Website Name\robots.txt"
```

Hopefully this is a useful example for others in the future.