# Copy css/js files with msdeploy on one-click deployment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msdeploy

I deployed my ASP.NET MVC 5 application using the one-click deployment in Visual Studio.

Meanwhile I need to copy some css/js files to a centralized folder, so that they can be used from different applications of my solution.

It seems that msdeploy has [some options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905248/msdeploy-sync-command-to-copy-files-to-subfolder-of-iis-app) to solve this. But where/how can I pass parameters to msdeploy using Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 1):

One of options is:

we need some class that inherits Task. It will copy files.

```
public class CopyFilesToFolder : Task
{
    [Required]
    public string FolderPathForSource { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string OutputFolder { get; set; }

    public override bool Execute()
    {
        //Do copy here

        return true;
    }
}
```

For example YouProject is the what you want do deploy.

We need to edit YourProject.csproj file:
register dll with CopyFilesToFolder class and add target for MsDeploy

```
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <UsingTask TaskName="CopyFilesToFolder" AssemblyFile="..\..\pathTodll\dllWithCopyFilesToFolderClass.dll">
  </UsingTask>
  <Target Name="CopyFilesToFolderForPublish">
    <CopyFilesToFolder FolderPathForSource="$(ProjectDir)\\$(_PackageTempDir)\\Content\\" OutputFolder="C:\\Deploy\\Content\\">
    </CopyFilesToFolder>
  </Target>
<!-- ... -->

</Project>
```

As you see there we can pass parameters to class we create earlier.
And the last, in YourProject.pubxml file we told MsDeploy that when he putt together all files needed for package execute CopyFilesToFolderForPublish target

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Other properties -->
    <OnAfterCopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage>CopyFilesToFolderForPublish;</OnAfterCopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```